# Is it possible to run OS script from hawt.io plugin (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, hawtio

I've got Tomcat webcontainer (8.0.x) and hawt.io (1.5.10) that runs on top of it.

I would like to write Hawt.io plugin that would restart JVM server, the one that hosts this jvm.

Lets assume I've bash script that I can call to gracefully stop JVM and start it again.
Is it possible to call such external OS script from hawt.io plugin? 
Where do I find any code examples?

ps. I know this will disconnect requesting user from hawt.io web app. Script and jvm would run from the same uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible as a Hawtio plugin is nothing but a front-end AngularJS script which runs on browser. Running an OS script from a browser script is prohibited because otherwise it may open up all the possible security attacks.

One possible workaround would be to create a custom JMX MBean deployed on your Tomcat server which then runs a system command like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...")` internally, and have a Hawtio plugin to invoke the MBean from browser.